# Xpath parent selector in PHP

Tags: php, xml, model-view-controller, xpath

***A bit of background:***

Hi guys,

I'm creating a router in PHP for an MVC application on and decided that the structure would be in XML. I have an XML file containing all valid routes (pages) in the system along with their associated controller & action.

There's also a 'param' to indicate if there's a variable on the end of the URI and the variable name to assign it to (confusingly named I know!!)

What I'm doing is looking at the REQUEST_URI and using PHP's explode function to turn it into an array of 'route' elements which I then build a query for.

Here's some sample XML:

```
<routes>    
    <route>
        <url>blog</url>
        <params>
            <controller>blogController</controller>
            <action>indexAction</action>
        </params>

        <route>
            <url>entry</url>
            <params>
                <controller>blogController</controller>
                <action>entryAction</action>
                <param>entryId</param>
            </params>
        </route>
    </route>
 </routes>
```

And here's the query that's being built:

```
/routes/route/url[text()="blog"]/../route/url[text()="entry"]/..
```

This always seems to return 0 nodes in PHPs XPath, but using an online expression tester I get the entry route matched.

Can anyone explain what might be going wrong? Does PHP's Xpath parser understand this syntax? I have also tried the ::parent* method

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath wise I come to the same conclusion like DevNull, only a slight addition to select the first match:

```
/routes/route[url="blog"]/route[url="entry"][1]
```

With a object interface:

```
$routes = new RoutesXML($xml);

var_dump($routes->fromPath('blog/entry'));  # The SimpleXMLElement

var_dump($routes->fromPath('blog/entry2')); # NULL
```

Example Implementation:

```
class RoutesXML
{
    private $xml;
    public function __construct($xml) {
        $this->xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    }
    public function fromPath($path) {
        $expression = '/routes';
        foreach(explode('/', $path) as $element)
            $expression .= "/route[url='$element']";
        $expression .= '[1]';
        list($route) = $this->xml->xpath($expression) + array(NULL);
        return $route;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need `..` or `parent::*`.

Try this instead:

```
/routes/route[url="blog"]/route[url="entry"]
```

You shouldn't need `text()` either, but I also don't know PHP very well. Ff the above doesn't work, try:

```
/routes/route[url/text()="blog"]/route[url/text()="entry"]
```

Comment: The reason to traverse back to the parent is that other routes aren't inside the 'url' node, they're inside its parent.

Comment: @managedheap84 - Right, but this can be specified in the predicates. In the xpath in my answer, the route returned isn't in a url. It's in a route. If you take the predicates off, it's `/routes/route/route`.